# Is there a way to let the Get-Process Cmdlet output only the Name of a Process? [Powershell]

Tags: string, powershell, process, format, data-manipulation

the Title says basicly what im looking for.

```
array = Get-Process * | Select Name
```

Im saving the output of Get-Process in an array and want to output a specific process to a .txt file.
But whatever parameter im trying the output always looks like this:

[Output in .txt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cymr3.png)

I tried to save the output in a string and modify it there (String.Replace(), String.Substring() and String.TrimStart()) but that changed nothing.

```
$entry.Replace("Name", $null)
$entry.Replace("----", $null)

$entry.Replace("Name", "")
$entry.Replace("----", "")

$entry.Substring("8")

$entry.TrimStart("Name")
$entry.TrimStart("----")
```

Im also adding my complete Code if that helps (its obv. not finished). Thanks in advance for helping me :)

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System;
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing;


Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
Clear-Content alleProzesse.txt -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

function Get-ScriptDirectory 
{
    $Invocation = (Get-Variable MyInvocation -Scope 1).Value
    Split-Path $Invocation.MyCommand.Path
}

$path = Get-ScriptDirectory
$input = Get-Content $path\prozess.txt -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
echo $input
$msg = "Programm " + $input +" geschlossen"
$msg2 = "Programm " + $input +" geöffnet"
$msg3 = "Programm " + $input +" nicht gefunden"

if($input -eq $null)
{
    $array = @()
    $array = Get-Process * | Select Name
    $i = $array.Length

    $form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
    $form.Text = 'Select a Computer'
    $form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(500,400)
    $form.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'

    $okButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $okButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(75,320)
    $okButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
    $okButton.Text = 'OK'
    $okButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK
    $form.AcceptButton = $okButton
    $form.Controls.Add($okButton)

    $cancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $cancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(150,320)
    $cancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
    $cancelButton.Text = 'Cancel'
    $cancelButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel
    $form.CancelButton = $cancelButton
    $form.Controls.Add($cancelButton)

    $label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,20)
    $label.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(480,20)
    $label.Text = 'Please select a computer:'
    $form.Controls.Add($label)

    $listBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox
    $listBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,40)
    $listBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(460,200)
    $listBox.Height = 250


    for($x=1 ; $x -le $i; $x++) 
        {
        $entry = $array[$x] 
        $entry.Replace("Name", $null)
        $entry.Replace("----", $null)
        #$entry = $entry.Substring("8")
        #$entry = $entry.TrimStart("Name")
        #$entry = $entry.TrimStart("----")
        [void] $listbox.Items.Add($entry)
        }

    $form.Controls.Add($listBox)

    $form.Topmost = $true

    $result = $form.ShowDialog()

    if ($result -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK)
    {
      
    $output = $listBox.SelectedItem
    
    if($output -eq $null)
        {
        exit
        echo "kein Prozess gewählt - Exit"
        }
         
    Clear-Content $path\testtxt.txt -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
     echo $output + " wurde als zu überwachendes Programm festgelegt."
     echo $output >> $path\prozess.txt
       
    
    }



    }
    else
    {
    $task = Get-Process $input -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if($task -eq $null)
        {
         echo "Prozess nicht verfügbar"
         exit
        }
        else
        {
         echo "Prozess läuft"
         exit
        }
}
```

Comment: what language is that?  idc, but put it in the question's tag(s)...

Comment: Its powershell. I dont think there is a questions tag availiable :/

Comment: there is, and I've added it for you (pending approval...).

Comment: Thanks, i thought you meant the tag "questions" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you do not want the column header.

You can try this:

```
$array = (Get-Process *).Name
```

To output it to a .txt file you can use:

```
$array | Out-File -FilePath .\processes.txt
```